# Android SimpleDateFormat format issue

Tags: android, android-date

I am trying to format a date into required format. but i receive wrong date out put.
here is what i am doing.

I receive the dates as following:

```
3/24/2012 8:25:03 AM
3/23/2012 2:57:01 PM
3/15/2012 9:28:01 AM
```

And want to show them as

```
Sun, Mar 24
Sat, Mar 23
Tue, Mar 15
```

Code I am using is as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, MMM dd");

Date dt = sourceFormat.parse("3/24/2012 8:25:03 AM");
String desiredDateString1 = desiredFormat.format(dt)

dt = sourceFormat.parse("3/23/2012 2:57:01 PM");
String desiredDateString2 = desiredFormat.format(dt)

dt = sourceFormat.parse("3/15/2012 9:28:01 AM");
String desiredDateString3 = desiredFormat.format(dt)
```

But instead of getting correct output, i get

```
desiredDateString1 = "Tue, Jan 24"
desiredDateString2 = "Mon, Jan 23"
desiredDateString3 = "Sun, Jan 15"
```

It Conciders the month as **Jan** instead of **Mar** ... y?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

mm means minute in the hour. you should use MM

try with

```
SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```